# Who was Sri Vathsa Somadeva Sharma and how valid are the following shortcut mantras/slokas?

Tags: scripture, gods, mantras, shloka

Several short Slokas/Mantras are found on [this](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Slokas_for_solving_various_problems) page and they are said to be compiled by Sri Vatsha Somadeva Sharma.

The mantras are shortcut ways of solving various day to day problems and are also claimed to be useful for achieving several other benefits.

It is claimed, for example, that by chanting the following mantra three times one is supposed to get the benefits of chanting the Shiva Sahasranama Stotram:

> Shivo, Maheswaraschaiva , Rudhro , Vishnu , pithamaha , SAmsara
>   Vaidhya , Sarvesa , Paramathma SAdashiva.

And, one is supposed to get the benefits of doing a Homa 
/Yagna by chanting this rather simple mantra/sloka:

> Namaskara Smrutho Yagna , sarva Yagna , uthamam, Uthama , Namami
>   sathatham Samedhava Praseedathu.

Further slokas:

> **53.Places of salvation**
>
> Daasanath Abra sadasi , jananath Kamalalaye , Kasyanthu maranath
>   mukthi , Smaranath arunachale
>
> **6.To avoid bad dreams (Chant 3 times before retiring to bed)**
>
> Achyutham, Kesavam , Vishnum , Harim , SAthyam , Janardhanam, Hamsam
>   Narayanam Krishnam japeth Duswapna SAnthaye.
>
> **For increase in knowledge , to pass in examination (this has to be
>   chanted eight times in the morning**
>
> 15.Bhashyathi sarva sashtraani , yechanye niyamaa thadhaa , Aksharanicha sarvaani thwanthu devu namosthuthe.
>
> **17.To destroy sin committed by the mind (This has to be chanted eight times at dawn and dusk)**
>
> Vibhatheeya Shivasane , Shivena saakam avyaya, Hiranmaye Athinirmale
>   Namami thaam Himathrijaam.

Question-How authentic/valid are these mantras/slokas and who was Sri Sharma who compiled  them?