# Origin of sloka दर्शनादभ्रसादसि

Tags: puranas, skanda-purana

दर्शनादभ्रसादसि जननात्कमलालये ॥
काश्यन्तु मरणान्मुक्तिः स्मरणादरुणाचले ॥

It means one can get moksha  by either of having darsan of Abhrasadasi (Chidambaram), dying at Kasi, birth at Kamalalaya and remembering Arunachala.

Which Khanda and Chapter of Skanda Purana has the above sloka? Does any other purana also contain this sloka?

Comment: I used read this sloka each day :).U can chk my question here-http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10715/who-was-sri-vathsa-somadeva-sharma-and-how-valid-are-the-following-shortcut-mant..  Many such  short slokas(including the one in Q) are given by Somadeva Sharma.Mite be u can identify scriptural sources for some of them.

Comment: I think Arunachala Mahatmya of Skandha Purana contains this...